# Python: Unable to extract multi-line 'Property Address' from PDF

Tags: text-extraction, pdftotext

Need your help to write a python script to extract multi-line text from a pdf file [MultiLineText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYaX5.png). Here's the codelet I tried to use: 'Address': r'Property No: (\d+)'

No matter what combination of regex I use, the I am hitting blank. The text that needs extraction looks like this:
Property No: 1121546
**7 WARATAH GROVE
WENDOUREE 3355**

Note that Property No: 1121546 is plain text and **7 WARATAH GROVE** & **WENDOUREE 3355** are **BOLD**

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Sai

Comment: I didn't understand. If you have a code, pls share